# Issues with intel sound card on HP Omen

Tags: arch-linux, audio, kde, alsa

I recently installed Archlinux, everything works fine, but the sound card is not recognized by alsamixer or KDE.

I followed several solutions on the internet but I do not know what else to do to make it work.

> cat /proc/asound/cards

```
 0 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                      HDA NVidia at 0xdc080000 irq 17
```

> lspci -vnn | grep -A 1 -i audio

```
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS [8086:a348] (rev 10)
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Cannon Lake PCH cAVS [103c:8603]
--
        Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci
--
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:10f9] (rev a1)
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company TU106 High Definition Audio Controller [103c:8603]
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
```

> pactl list cards

```
Card #0
        Name: alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1
        Driver: module-alsa-card.c
        Owner Module: 6
        Properties:
                alsa.card = "0"
                alsa.card_name = "HDA NVidia"
                alsa.long_card_name = "HDA NVidia at 0xdc080000 irq 17"
                alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
                device.bus_path = "pci-0000:01:00.1"
                sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card0"
                device.bus = "pci"
                device.vendor.id = "10de"
                device.vendor.name = "NVIDIA Corporation"
                device.product.id = "10f9"
                device.product.name = "TU106 High Definition Audio Controller"
                device.string = "0"
                device.description = "TU106 High Definition Audio Controller"
                module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
        Profiles:
                output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5900, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 800, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 800, available: no)
                output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5700, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
                output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5700, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
                output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 600, available: no)
                off: Off (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)
        Active Profile: off
        Ports:
                hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority: 5900, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
                        Properties:
                                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                        Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo, output:hdmi-surround, output:hdmi-surround71
                hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority: 5800, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
                        Properties:
                                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                        Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo-extra1, output:hdmi-surround-extra1, output:hdmi-surround71-extra1
                hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (priority: 5700, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
                        Properties:
                                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                        Part of profile(s): output:hdmi-stereo-extra2, output:hdmi-surround-extra2, output:hdmi-surround71-extra2
```

if you want more informations : http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=59016dde811a3991061dd4bfb3b597bd55e26b3f

Thank you in advance for your help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution who work for me with headphones :

In file : **/etc/pulse/default.pa**

I add :

```
load-module module-alsa-source device=hw:0,0
```

And in kernel parms in grubs : **/etc/default/grub**

```
snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0
```

And after update GRUB config